# How to use Get Data From Web in Excel from site needing authentication

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I use Excel's Get Data > From Web (Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web) feature when the desired web page is behind a login?

Comment: You need to authenticate since it's protected,, by Login method,, find the method on Login page if you are not member,, some sites allows Gmail/Facebook Ids to login or instantly create an Id!

Comment: I have the login details already. I'm already logged in in my default browser, but when Excel tries to fetch the data, it gets the content from the login page, not the page I'm trying to access.

Comment: ,, may be threads are linked with the data Table,, difficult to say the reason since don't know what site you are connecting with!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "may be threads are linked with the data Table"?

The site I'm connecting to is a site I'm running on my machine (in development mode).